# Is it possible to turn a flutter "ListView" into a "ReorderableListView"?

Tags: flutter

I have been using "Listview.builder" to build lists:

```
          : ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _substances.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
      color: Colors.purple[200],
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: ListTile(
          title: Text(_substances[index]['substanceName']),
          subtitle: Text(_substances[index]['substanceType']),
          trailing: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () => _showForm(_substances[index]['id']),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                  onPressed: () =>
                      _deleteItem(_substances[index]['id']),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    ),
  ),
```

I want to be able to rearrange those lists as entries are added or, in some cases, have them automatically arranged alphabetically.

I have tried various ways of rewriting the "Listview" as "ReorderableListView," but without any success. Could it be that "Reorderable" needs an existing "List"?

```
    return ReorderableListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
  proxyDecorator: proxyDecorator,
  onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }
      final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
      _items.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  },
  children: cards,
);
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing while using `ReorderableListView`?

Comment: I was having trouble when I substituted `ReorderableListView` for `ListView` and add `onReorder: _onReorder,` near the end, but right now having trouble with java (I think), because my network administrator updated Windows yesterday, and now nothing is working properly...

I will get back to this on Monday...

Comment: OK: "Every item of ReorderableListView must have a key."

Answer (score 1):

```
  return ReorderableListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
  itemCount: _substances.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Card(
      key: Key('$index'), // Important: Assign a unique key to each item
      color: Colors.purple[200],
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(_substances[index]['substanceName']),
        subtitle: Text(_substances[index]['substanceType']),
        trailing: SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                onPressed: () => _showForm(_substances[index]['id']),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                onPressed: () => _deleteItem(_substances[index]['id']),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }
      final Map<String, dynamic> item = _substances.removeAt(oldIndex);
      _substances.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  },
);
```

Try this, the problem when using reorderableListView  is that the list can be dynamic based on the length of _substances.

there were 4 changes mainly

1. Used ReorderableListView.builder instead of ReorderableListView.
2. Assigned a unique Key to each item in the list. This is crucial for the ReorderableListView to keep track of items during reordering.

3)Implemented the itemBuilder to dynamically build the list items using Card and ListTile.

these 3 are kind of very crucial to have a properly implemented ReordarableListView

Hope this answers your question, if there is anything else feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks!

That solves the main problem, but adds a few more. I'm getting "Null check operator used on a null value" if I try to add an item after reordering., The page crashed (jumped back to the previous screen) a few times, but I can't seem to reproduce that right now... too many new entries? just a momentary glitch?

Also, if I leave this screen and come back to it, everything reverts to its original order, so I will have to figure out a way to save the reordered list. And I only seem to be able to reorder one item per screen view.

Anyway: thanks for giving me something to work with!